Shopware themeSalesChannelRepository fails without debug info
Shopware suppresses errors in mail template-context for some reason. So the following code fails without any debug info.
$themeSalesChannelResult = $this->themeSalesChannelRepository->search(new Criteria(), $context);
My goal is to retrieve the themeId when having a salesChannelId.
    private function getThemeId(Context $context): ?string {
        $salesChannelId = $context->getSource()->getSalesChannelId();
        $salesChannelCriteria = new Criteria([$salesChannelId]);
        $salesChannel = $this->salesChannelRepository->search($salesChannelCriteria, $context)->first();

        if (!$salesChannel) {
            return null;
        }

        // TEST
        $themeSalesChannelResult = $this->themeSalesChannelRepository->search(new Criteria(), $context);
        dd($this->themeSalesChannelRepository);

        $themeSalesChannelCriteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('salesChannelId', $salesChannelId));
        $themeSalesChannelResult = $this->themeSalesChannelRepository->search($themeSalesChannelCriteria, $context);

        if (!$themeSalesChannelResult) {
            return null;
        }

        return $themeSalesChannelResult->first()->getThemeId();
    }



dd($this->themeSalesChannelRepository)

dd($context)

